# Looking for the closest element in XPath

Tags: python, xml, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I'm trying to **scrap/select** all the tables  that have '**Consolidated Schedule of Investments**' in the title but the problem is that for each pages it **exists in a different position** or html structure for those pages :

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1287750/000128775023000021/arcc-20230331.htm
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1633336/000095017023020540/ccap-20230331.htm
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1534254/000153425423000008/cion-20230331.htm

This code will select the element, but the next step is to select the closest table to it, either if it's sibiling ascendent or descendant :

`//span[contains(translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 'CONSOLIDATED SCHEDULE OF INVESTMENTS')]`

Comment: **Consolidated Schedule of Investments** is within a table and each page have only one table. Which sibiling ascendent or descendant are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `ancestor` and `descendant` and `following` e.g.

```
//span[contains(translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 'CONSOLIDATED SCHEDULE OF INVESTMENTS')]/(ancestor::table[1] | descendant::table[1] | following::table[1])[1]
```

the `(ancestor::table[1] | descendant::table[1] | following::table[1])[1]` should take care of "either if it's sibiling ascendent or descendant".

Note: the used syntax is only supported in current XPath (i.e. not in 1.0) so I am not quite sure you can use it; in the Python world there are at least two options to use the current version 3.1 of XPath, namely ElementPath https://pypi.org/project/elementpath/ and SaxonCHE https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/.

Comment: The web page might containt multiple tables

Comment: @MohamedGrich, yes, but the XPath expression I posted would take care of it; only it looks as the syntax I used is not supported in XPath 1.0 so in the Python world to use XPath 2 or 3 use ElementPath or SaxonC.